# wso2 esb and cep installation simultaneouslly

Tags: wso2, wso2-cep, wso2-esb

I am trying to install and run ESB and CEP both on the same machine. I have tried to set port offset to 1, to prevent port conflict, but still after running ESB, I am not able to run CEP. The error log in cmd is as bellow:

```
`C:\Program Files\yajsw-stable-11.03_cep\bat>call setenv.bat
"java" -Xmx30m -Djna_tmpdir="C:\Program Files\yajsw-stable-11.03_cep\bat\/../tmp
" -jar "C:\Program Files\yajsw-stable-11.03_cep\bat\/../wrapper.jar" -t     "C:\Program Files\yajsw-stable-11.03_cep\bat\/../conf/wrapper.conf"
YAJSW: yajsw-stable-11.03
OS   : Windows 7/6.1/amd64
JVM  : Oracle Corporation/1.7.0_75
Dec 20, 2015 11:44:31 AM org.apache.commons.vfs2.VfsLog info
INFO: Using "C:\Users\K5563~1.KHA\AppData\Local\Temp\vfs_cache" as temporary files store.
platform null
************* STARTING "WSO2CARBON_cep" ***********************

Service "WSO2CARBON_cep" NOT started
Press any key to continue . . .`
```

First : where and how can I find a proper log to figure out what is the problem? As you know, there is nothing in : repository\logs until the program starts to run.
Second : if you have any idea about the probable cause, please let me know.

Additional info : I am using jdk 1.7.0_75, esb 4.9.0, cep 4.0.0, yajsw 11.03, and there was a success message after installation of both esb and cep. I gave them different service names while installing as a windows service, to prevent conflict. Also, I am able to see both of them in windows services list.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Does CEP start without port offsetting? If it works, did you try by starting CEP on default port and starting ESB in port offsetting?

Answer (score 0):

To start two carbon servers as windows services please follow the blog post below[1] to overcome this issue. The blog explains how two services can be run as windows services.

Some important areas to consider when setting up two nodes as windows services are :
1.create two folders as 'esb_service' and 'cep_service' and copy the relevant packs into each foldr

2.As shown on[1] please update the esb_home and cep_home on the relevant places within the wrapper.conf replacing the carbon_home which is the default value

3.Make sure that the port offset of one of the two nodes is incremented by one to avoid port conflict.

4.start the two yajsw-stable-11.03 with installService.bat and startService.bat to get the services running

Note: I have tried this scenario using yajsw-stable-11.03 version.

[1]http://blog.lasindu.com/2015/05/how-to-start-two-or-more-wso2-servers.html