# Unable to run wso2 cep

Tags: wso2

I have a problem in running both wso2 esb and cep simultaneously. I asked it here :
[wso2 esb and cep installation simultaneouslly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34379310/wso2-esb-and-cep-installation-simultaneouslly)
Considering this background, I decided to run them one at a time. So I started the esb and everything looked good. But after shutting down the esb and starting cep, it looks like everything is not ok with it. I am not able to see some menues like 'Event Processor Configs' , or 'Input Event Adaptors'. Am I missing something, or is it because of the difference with older versions of cep and move of those menus to somewhere else?

Additional info : I loged in with 'admin/admin' user, and a pic of my cep menus is attached to this question.

Thanks for reading.[image]

Comment: what is the CEP version that you are using? According to the screeenshot you are in the configuration menu. CEP related functionalities are in Main menu

Answer (score 0):

If you are running two servers in the same machine, then you have to run one of the two servers with an offset, else there can be issues due to port conflict. Refer https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Glossary#Glossary-Portoffset

If you have started the servers with two different ports then you can find their primary operations from the main menu, which is located on the left side panel.

Suho